# Java multithreaded server explanation please

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I am making a client server program and I am making a multithreaded server so it can handle multiple clients at once. I have looked at examples but there is something that is confusing me with how they work.
The two classes:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServerThread.java

are used for a multithreaded server, the part that confuses me though is the following:

```
while (listening) {
            new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
        }
```

To me it looks like the server is creating a infinite amount of KKMultiServerThreads and when the socket didn't have a connection it just passes null through. How does this work?

Comment: If you don't already do so, start reading the Java API doc before asking these type of questions. It usually describes this type of information in considerable detail. For example [`ServerSocket.accept()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) says: _"Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method **blocks until a connection is made**."_ (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen your code.But i hava some idea about the question.     The

```
    serverSocket.accept()
```

is a blocking way(function). If you don't input something , the program would be waiting for your input.I think it will not be return null automaticlly.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

`ServerSocket.accept()` blocks until an incoming connection occurs. It doesn't return null.